# Create a files up to a certain number

Tags: python, logging

I have a logger that creates a new file every run. On a new run, I am renaming the log before writing (see code snippet) to keep the last log. How can I modify the code to save the `N` past logs? I can loop through all `N` files and "move" them back by 1 (0 to 1, 1 to 2 etc) and also delete all logs after `N` but that is not very pretty. Any better suggestions?

```py
folder = "/home/user/log/"
log_path = os.path.join(folder, 'run.log')
backup_log(log_path) # renames run.log to run0.log and overwrites it if exists
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', filename=log_path,level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the source code for [`RotatingFileHandler.doRollover()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6ae2780be0667a8dc52c4fb583171ec86067d700/Lib/logging/handlers.py#L158), from the built-in logging module:

it does indeed loop through every file and rename it, there's no "prettier" way to do it in bulk.

```py
    def doRollover(self):
        """
        Do a rollover, as described in __init__().
        """
        if self.stream:
            self.stream.close()
            self.stream = None
        if self.backupCount > 0:
            for i in range(self.backupCount - 1, 0, -1):
                sfn = self.rotation_filename("%s.%d" % (self.baseFilename, i))
                dfn = self.rotation_filename("%s.%d" % (self.baseFilename,
                                                        i + 1))
                if os.path.exists(sfn):
                    if os.path.exists(dfn):
                        os.remove(dfn)
                    os.rename(sfn, dfn)
            dfn = self.rotation_filename(self.baseFilename + ".1")
            if os.path.exists(dfn):
                os.remove(dfn)
            self.rotate(self.baseFilename, dfn)
        if not self.delay:
            self.stream = self._open()
```

NOTE: It doesn't seem like you can use this Handler directly instead of your custom one, because it doesn't rotate files for every run (like you seem to need)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I see at least 3 options.
You could append your old log with new data.
Or youc could add datetime to your file name (and delete the lates each time you create a new one).
You could also create a folder for your log files and a variable that indicates the current log number. For example, you have 5 logs and do not what to make any more, just null this variable so your program will override the log_0 file. You can add datetime info to the top of this file.